How to trigger a MacroDroid Webhook
I am trying to trigger a macrodroid webhook from my app via http post but i can't figure it out. Can someone help me?
The url is correct and works because i can trigger it with NodeRed http post node.
String string_url = "https://trigger.macrodroid.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

public void webhook_post(String string_url) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(string_url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("application/json", "ok");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

